# Check if float is close to any float stored in array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, floating-point

I need to check if a given float is close, within a given tolerance, to *any float* in an array of floats.

```
import numpy as np

# My float
a = 0.27
# The tolerance
t = 0.01
# Array of floats
arr_f = np.arange(0.05, 0.75, 0.008)
```

Is there a simple way to do this? Something like `if a in arr_f:` but allowing for some tolerance in the difference?

---

**Add**

By "allow tolerance" I mean it in the following sense:

```
for i in arr_f:
    if abs(a - i) <= t:
        print 'float a is in arr_f within tolerance t'
        break
```

Comment: do you look for a solution simple to write and maintain or you need a sophisticated approach to achieve better performance?

Comment: i think `numpy.isclose(a,arr_f, atol=t)` is best answer as you see below!

Comment: @Kasra, why is that better than `(abs(arr_f - a) < t).any()`?

Comment: @Yoel your answer is good too , but other useed `numpy` method ! and its advantage if this !

Comment: @Kasra, I don't think that is relevant, especially since this approach is faster, but I guess to each his own, lol :-)

Comment: Often (but not necessarily in your case), you want a relative error, along the lines of `abs(arr_f - a) / max(abs(arr_f), abs(a))` and a value for the tolerance of perhaps `1E-5` or `1E-6`.  I expect numpy provides a mechanism for that, too; the [`isclose()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html?highlight=isclose#numpy.isclose) method might provide it — indeed, instead of the `atol=t` suggested, you could use `rtol=t` to specify a relative tolerance.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

How about using [`np.isclose`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html)?

```
>>> np.isclose(arr_f, a, atol=0.01).any()
True
```

`np.isclose` compares two objects element-wise to see if the values are within a given tolerance (here specified by the keyword argument `atol` which is the absolute difference between two elements). The function returns a boolean array.

Comment: The problem of this answer is that it makes all the comparisons before performing the `any` operation, while ordinary `any` stops when encountering the first `False`. So using instead `any(np.isclose(ar, a, atol=0.01) for ar in arr_f)` seems more memory-efficient.

Comment: @Dr_Zaszuś if working on machines with _very_ limited RAM, that could _possibly_ be an issue. Otherwise, building additional boolean arrays to reduce is almost never a problem, even when working with very large arrays. In cases where the array is massive enough to threaten the limits of the programmer's available memory, then `any(np.isclose(ar, a, atol=0.01) for ar in arr_f)` is likely to be unacceptably slow. How long does that code take when `arr_f` holds 1 million values and `a` is not close to any of them? It's **27s** for me (and only 4ms with `isclose`/`any`)!

Answer (score 8):

If you're only interested in a `True`/`False` result, then this should work:

```
In [1]: (abs(arr_f - a) < t).any()
Out[1]: True
```

Explanation: `abs(arr_f - a) < t` returns a boolean array on which `any()` is invoked in order to find out whether *any* of its values is `True`.

**EDIT** - Comparing this approach and the one suggested in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25962971/3903832) reveals that this one is slightly faster:

```
In [37]: arr_f = np.arange(0.05, 0.75, 0.008)

In [38]: timeit (abs(arr_f - a) < t).any()
100000 loops, best of 3: 11.5 µs per loop

In [39]: timeit np.isclose(arr_f, a, atol=t).any()
10000 loops, best of 3: 44.7 µs per loop

In [40]: arr_f = np.arange(0.05, 1000000, 0.008)

In [41]: timeit (abs(arr_f - a) < t).any()
1 loops, best of 3: 646 ms per loop

In [42]: timeit np.isclose(arr_f, a, atol=t).any()
1 loops, best of 3: 802 ms per loop
```

---

An alternative solution that also returns the relevant indices is as follows:

```
In [5]: np.where(abs(arr_f - a) < t)[0]
Out[5]: array([27, 28])
```

This means that the values residing in indices 27 and 28 of `arr_f` are within the desired range, and indeed:

```
In [9]: arr_f[27]
Out[9]: 0.26600000000000001

In [10]: arr_f[28]
Out[10]: 0.27400000000000002
```

Using this approach can also generate a `True`/`False` result:

```
In [11]: np.where(abs(arr_f - a) < t)[0].any()
Out[11]: True
```

Comment: Very good answer too. I was looking for something more "out of the box" already packed into python or numpy, but I'll definitely keep in mins the better performance of doing it this way. Cheers.

Answer (score -1):

```py
[temp] = np.where(np.int32((sliceArray - aimFloat) > 0) == 1)
```

`temp[0]` is answer.
sliceArray is sorted!